# How to save the partition key in a file using Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I'm using java 8 for creating my first Spark job.

I have a `JavaRDD<Row>` with the following schema:

`List<StructField> fields = Arrays.asList(
        DataTypes.createStructField("lastName", DataTypes.StringType, false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("firstName", DataTypes.StringType, false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.LongType, false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("gender", DataTypes.StringType, false));`

I would like to save this data into files grouped by `lastName` column - so I did that:

`dff
        .repartition(1)
        .write()
        .mode (SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .partitionBy("lastName")
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
        .option("header", "true")
        .csv(cmd.getOptionValue("dir"));`

And I got several directories (`lastName=*something*`) and each contains a file that starts with part-X.

BUT - I want the `lastName` column to also be part of the files' content - is that possible? and if it is - how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible by default But there are some workarounds for this case.

- By adding new field called `LastName` and populate same data from `lastName` column.

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq(("1","a"),("2","b")).toDF("LastName","lastname")

//allow casesensitive
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
//here we are partition by lastname and file will have LastName data
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("lastname").save("<path>")

//read from the from
spark.read.parquet("<path>").show()
//+--------+--------+
//|LastName|lastname|
//+--------+--------+
//|       2|       b|
//|       1|       a|
//+--------+--------+
```

Other way would be you can add `new column`(something other than lastname) and populate data from `lastName` then after reading the data from csv file rename the new column to `lastName`.